# In Selenium, how to access ChromeDriver which path is placed in another class?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Automation Testing. How can I access ChromeDriver which path is placed in another class of same package?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your question you need to add reference to the dll of the driver present in other class library and then you can access it.in case of Visual Studio you can add references by right clicking on the reference tab in the solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Use static variable.

```
  package pkg_name;
    public class class1 {       
       public static String sPath="D:\\chromedriver\\Chromedriver.exe";     
    }
```

```
package pkg_name;
import pkg_name.class1

    public class class2 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

            System.out.println(class1.sPath);   

        }
    }
```

OR 
You can declare public variable and create instance of the class inside second class like this.

```
package pkg_name;
public class class1 {
    public String sPath="D:\\chromedriver\\Chromedriver.exe";

}
```

```
package pkg_name;
import pkg_name.class1
public class class2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        class1 c1=new class1();
        System.out.println(c1.sPath);   

    }
    }
```